# How deal with commas in a CSV file when trying to put excel functions in cell value

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, csv

I'm trying to put a value inside a csv cell, which is actually an excel function.
It could have worked, except for the fact the commas are delimiters in csv files.
When I try for instance to put the following, the csv is creating more columns instead of just put the function in the cell:

```
DATE(2014, 03, 15)
```

It doesn't work because of the the commas. Any solution anyone?

Comment: can you show more code, like using vb or c# to put a value in a cell.  that snippet lacks all context

Comment: The CSV format does not support formulas. It is a plain text only format. Create a real excel file, for example with `EPPlus`.

Comment: If my memory serves me correctly, importing formulas from CSV is not possible. You could try to place your value between quotes, but I don't think that will help

Comment: Are you trying to have the function actually do something in the csv?  Or just store it for later use?

Comment: I found it. If anyone has reputation above 10 they can put it. I just added quotes around all the expression of the function.  'Rytis I' also said it. For instance "=DATE(2014, 03, 15)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, try adding double quotes around your data like so:

```
"=Date(2014, 03, 15)"
```

You may also want to look into a 3rd party library like `Epplus`.  If you're dealing with a lot of formulas it will make your life much easier than trying to format your data as a csv file.  Check it out [here](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).